# The Transforms in the Torchvision isn't working

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, torchvision

This is my first post, please cut me some slack...
Anyway having installed torch and torchvision, I was greeted with

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 from torchvision import models, transform
2 import torch

ImportError: cannot import name 'transform' from 'torchvision' (C:\Users\bala006\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchvision_*init*_.py)

Yes, this is in Jupyter, but for some reason, the models and the datasets worked but the transforms don't work...
Please help.

Comment: `torchvision.transform` isn't a submodule of `torchvision`. It should be `torchvision.transforms`.

Comment: Funnily enough. That worked. That actually worked. You're joking but it worked. Thanks. I'm a noob.